# Element takes up 100% width when text wraps (flexbox)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm working on a project and I'm having some problems with understanding how this CSS behavior works.

Take a look at this pen where I recreated a very basic scenario:
https://codepen.io/BroderBen/pen/MXrMyy

```
//Markup
<h2>This is how it looks now:</h2>
<div class="parent">
  <h3> Hello Hello </h3>
  <h3>
    Helloooooooooo Helloooooooooo 
  </h3>
</div>

<h2>width: min-content makes text break prematurely (first segment with hello hello):</h2>
<div class="parent">
  <h3 class="min-content"> Hello Hello </h3>
  <h3 class="min-content">
    Helloooooooooo Helloooooooooo 
  </h3>
</div>

<br/>
<h2>This is how I want it to look, but automaticly (not with br tags):</h2>

<div class="parent">
  <h3> Hello Hello </h3>
  <h3>
    Helloooooooooo <br/> Helloooooooooo 
  </h3>
</div>

//CSS
.parent{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
}
h3{
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
//added min-content class to showcase problems
.min-content{
  width: min-content;
}
```

I have some text with a border-bottom, the width is relative to the text inside, so the border only "covers" the area under the text.

The problem comes when there's too much text so it wraps to a second line, then the child takes upp 100% of the parent, even though there's alot of white at the side.

The parent needs to be a flex container, so I don't think the table / table-cell trick will work.

I've tried min-content, but then it wraps the text before it reaches the width of the parent and max-content seems to not break it at all.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using table-cell "hack". The pen is updated with the solution.

I found this example and followed it: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/h34pL/

```
:after {
    content: "";
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}
```

edit: 
In my case I had to use :after and :before. Tweaked the % to 15% on each side which worked for the different text that could take up this space.

It's not a "all around" solution though, works for my specific case.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by adding text align and width styles:

```
text-align: center;
width: min-content;
```

Hope this helps :>

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
}
h3{
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
width: min-content;
}
```

```html
<h2>This is how it looks now:</h2>
<div class="parent">
  <h3> Hello Hello </h3>
  <h3>
    Helloooooooooo Helloooooooooo 
  </h3>
</div>

<br/>
<h2>This is how I want it to look, but automaticly (not with br tags):</h2>

<div class="parent">
  <h3> Hello Hello </h3>
  <h3>
    Helloooooooooo <br/> Helloooooooooo 
  </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Added min-content class to pen to showcase that this setting breaks words before the width of the parent is reached.